# jquery load property on image

Tags: jquery, image, image-size

why this is not working?

```
<script>    
$('#draggable3').load(function() {
 alert($("#draggable3").width());
 $("#containment-wrapper").width() = $("#draggable3").width() * 1.3;
 $("#containment-wrapper").height() = $("#draggable3").height() * 1.3;

});
</script>
<body>
<div id="containment-wrapper">
<div id="border-ornament"> 

<img id="draggable3" class="draggable ui-widget-content" src="img.jpg">

</div>
</div>
</body>
```

why event .load not working after image is loaded?

Comment: What *does* happen? Anything at all? Errors?

Comment: try : `$("#containment-wrapper").width($("#draggable3").width() * 1.3);`.

Comment: the problem that this block isn't working at all

Comment: check out this topic, it may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write width and height as -

```
$("#containment-wrapper").width($("#draggable3").width() * 1.3);
$("#containment-wrapper").height($("#draggable3").height() * 1.3);
```

and you need to write jquery in document.ready -

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#draggable3').load(function() {
     alert($("#draggable3").width());
     $("#containment-wrapper").width($("#draggable3").width() * 1.3);
     $("#containment-wrapper").height($("#draggable3").height() * 1.3);
  });
});   
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

At the time of the script working tag #draggable3 not yet exists.
Try do this in document.ready function like this

```
$(function () {
    $('#draggable3').load(function() {
     alert($("#draggable3").width());
     $("#containment-wrapper").width() = $("#draggable3").width() * 1.3;
     $("#containment-wrapper").height() = $("#draggable3").height() * 1.3;

    });
});
```

Or you can put your script after your img tag.